# Correct way to use async function inside a for-loop

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, protractor, angular-e2e

Recently, I got some error when running the E2E tests and the only change I made is adding the **checkColumns** logic in the original test code as following:

```
it('check search and sort', async () => {
  await checkLoadingAndResult();
  await checkColumns(table, ...columns); //newly added 
  await checkTableSorting();
});
```

The logic of checkColumns is like:

```
export async function checkColumns(table: Table, ...columns: string[]) {
  for (const col of columns) {
    expect(await table.isColumnDisplayed(col)).toBeTruthy(`${col} is not displayed`)
  }
}
```

The error message is like:

```
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:59536
```

I think maybe there's something wrong in the **checkColumns** function and I don't know whether it's a correct way to call async methods inside a for-loop. And I guess this for-loop is the cause of the error.

Comment: Assuming `table.isColumnDisplayed` returns a promise (is an `async` function), then yes, the way you're calling it is just fine.

Comment: Thanks T.J.Crowder! table.isColumnDisplayed() returns a promise. I have struggled with the ECONNREFUSED error for a whole day. Maybe I need to find other causes of this error.

Comment: Please show the code of function isColumnDisplayed(). And clarify your code can always pass  without `await checkColumns(table, ...columns); `  even now.  As `djiss` said, your error not seems to related to the `checkColumns()` according to my experience.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is not generated by your usage of async / await.
It is most likely displayed because the HTTP request sent failed due to a connection error, I had the issue on another framework and it was due to the webdriver that was not running.